# How can we Update join statement using multiple statements at once in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, join

How can we Update the join statement using multiple statements at once in Postgresql?

Comment: A single UPDATE statement will update exactly one table. If you need to update multiple tables, you need to run multiple UPDATE statements.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
name,
count(*)
FROM candidate
GROUP BY
name,
HAVING count(*) > 1;

Postgresql rank duplicates